# Number of significant digits in dplyr summarise

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having trouble getting the desired number of decimal places from summarise. Here is a simple example:

```
test2  <- data.frame(c("a","a","b","b"), c(245,246,247,248))
library(dplyr)
colnames(test2)  <- c("V1","V2")
group_by(test2,V1) %>% summarise(mean(V2))
```

The dataframe is:

```
  V1  V2
1  a 245
2  a 246
3  b 247
4  b 248
```

The output is:

```
 V1     `mean(V2)`
 <fctr>      <dbl>
1 a             246
2 b             248
```

I would like it to give me the means including the decimal place (i.e. 245.5 and 247.5)

Comment: I can't reproduce - works fine for me.

Comment: Maybe you've set your options for how many digits are printed? What do you see if you enter `getOption("digits")`? If you see `0`, reset to the default with `options(digits = 7)`.

Comment: I manually set digits to 22 in options, without any success. I can get the correct digits when I don't use group_by and summarise (i.e. filter the dataframe by a or b and take the mean)

Comment: You are probably using the latest RStudio? I would put a `%>% as.data.frame()` in the last line as a workaround.

Comment: What's your `dplyr` version?

Comment: thank you! that workaround worked. I tried updating my dplyr before posting the qestion

Comment: @www any idea why the workaround is necessary? At a glance, the issue appears to be integer/double type confusion.

Comment: @icj I think it is just a default print setting of dplyr and RStudio. With the latest version of RStudio, when printing a tibble, the output tend to be automatically rounded. I don’t know how to adjust it. So my workaround is covert it to be a data frame only for printing.

Comment: It looks like RStudio is ding some experimentation with printing tibbles. It seems like there is a mixed response so far. https://community.rstudio.com/t/tibble-1-4-1-printing-truncation-too-aggressive-column-headings-misaligned/4354/4 and https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-are-some-digits-in-the-tibble-output-faded-out-in-the-r-console-display/4330/10

Comment: I see the same thing and I'm using Emacs and ESS. The workaround proposed by @www worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

Because you are using `dplyr` tools, the resulting output is actually a tibble, which by default prints numbers with 3 **significant digits**  (see option `pillar.sigfig`). This is not the same as **number of digits after the period**. To obtain the latter, convert it simply to a data.frame: `as.data.frame`

Note that tibble's concept of **significant digits** is somehow complicated, and does not indicate how many digits after the period are represented, but *the minimum number of digits necessary to have a given accurate representation of the number* (I think 99.9%, see [discussion here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/why-are-some-digits-in-the-tibble-output-faded-out-in-the-r-console-display/4330/9)).

This means the number of digits printed depends on the "size" of your number:

```r
library(tibble)
packageVersion("tibble")
#> [1] '2.1.3'
packageVersion("pillar")
#> [1] '1.4.2'
tab <- tibble(x = c(0.1234, 1.1234, 10.1234, 100.1234, 1000.1234))

options(pillar.sigfig=3)
tab
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>          x
#>      <dbl>
#> 1    0.123
#> 2    1.12 
#> 3   10.1  
#> 4  100.   
#> 5 1000.

options(pillar.sigfig=4)
tab
#> # A tibble: 5 x 1
#>           x
#>       <dbl>
#> 1    0.1234
#> 2    1.123 
#> 3   10.12  
#> 4  100.1   
#> 5 1000.

as.data.frame(tab)
#>           x
#> 1    0.1234
#> 2    1.1234
#> 3   10.1234
#> 4  100.1234
#> 5 1000.1234
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This is what I recommend for working with data:
`options(tibble.pillar.subtle=FALSE, tibble.pillar.sigfig=9, tibble.pillar.min_title_chars=10)`

Answer (score 9):

This is one solution-

```r
test2  <- data.frame(c("a", "a", "b", "b"), c(245, 246, 247, 248))
library(dplyr)
colnames(test2)  <- c("V1", "V2")
group_by(test2, V1) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(mean(V2)) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, format, 1)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   V1    `mean(V2)`
#>   <fct> <chr>     
#> 1 a     245.5     
#> 2 b     247.5
```

Created on 2018-01-20 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.1.1.9000).

### **EDIT :**

If you want to keep it as numeric :

```r
test2  <- data.frame(c("a", "a", "b", "b"), c(245, 246, 247, 248))
library(dplyr)
colnames(test2)  <- c("V1", "V2")
group_by(test2, V1) %>% 
  dplyr::summarise(mean(V2)) %>% 
  as.data.frame(.) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 1)
```

Gives

```r
  V1 mean(V2)
1  a    245.5
2  b    247.5
```

And with another example (from @Matifou) :

```r
tab <- tibble(x = c(0.1234, 1.1234, 10.1234, 100.1234, 1000.1234))

tab %>%  
  as.data.frame(.) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)
```

Gives :

```r
        x
1    0.12
2    1.12
3   10.12
4  100.12
5 1000.12
```

Comment: I don't think that converting the numbers to characters was what the OP intended, just understanding the way those numbers are printed to the console

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution is the following:

```
test2  <- data.frame(c("a","a","b","b"), c(245,246,247,248))
library(dplyr)
colnames(test2)  <- c("V1","V2")
group_by(test2,V1) %>% summarise(`mean(V2)` = sprintf("%0.1f",mean(V2)))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
  V1    `mean(V2)`
  <fct> <chr>     
1 a     245.5     
2 b     247.5
```

Comment: This converts the value to a character- not helpful if you need this value for other computations or plotting as it will no longer be treated as a number.