# Mutate to modify values and replace

Tags: r, dplyr

Hi there I am trying to mutate values (e.g. changing kilograms to tonnes) and replace them in the original dataset but it doesn't seem to remain within the original dataset.

Here is a sample dataset for reference.

| Country | Type | Quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | Kilograms | 23132 |
| B | Kilograms | 34235 |
| C | Tonnes | 700 |

`library(dplyr)`

```
df %>%
 filter(Type == "Kilograms") %>%
 group_by(Quantity) %>%
 mutate(Quantity = Quantity /1000)
```

But I am not sure what to do the for next step, I tried the replace function but it didn't work.

Also, I plan to add a line at the end that changes all kilograms to tonnes, something like this:

```
df$Unit[df$Type == 'Kilograms'] <- 'Tonnes'
```

Comment: Did you try storing the df by using `df <- df %>% filter(Type == "Kilograms") %>% group_by(Quantity) %>% mutate(Quantity = Quantity /1000)` ? (note, this applies the filter to the df, but the general principle is that you need to store the end result)

Comment: @CIAndrews Ah yes so silly of me! Can't believe i spent hours on this just to realise I didn't store this, do you know how to modify the decimal places as some of the data shows 0.000?

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57599829/5785085

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `case_when()` which is dplyr's equivalent to SQL's `CASE WHEN`. Basically it allows you to vectorize multiple `if_else()` statements. Below, the first condition is the if statement and then `TRUE ~` is the else statement

```
df <- data.frame(Country = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
                 Type = c("Kilograms", "Kilograms", "Tonnes"),
                 Quantity = c(23132, 34235, 700))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Quantity = case_when(Type == 'Kilograms' ~ Quantity/1000,
                              TRUE ~ Quantity),
         Type = case_when(Type == 'Kilograms' ~ 'Tonnes',
                          TRUE ~ 'Tonnes')
         )
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ifelse` function to change the value based on other condition. This function also works weel with tidyverse environment.

Don't forget to reassign the result to original variable since pipe operator does not change the input data

```r
library(dplyr)
df = df %>% mutate(Quantity = ifelse(Type=="Kilograms",Quantity/1000,Quantity),
              Type = ifelse(Type=='Kilograms','Tonnes',Type))
```